# Will a backflow preventer cause clogs in a basement drain?

Tags: bathroom, basement

I have a backflow preventer basically in between my main plumbing stack and the basement bathroom. There’s never been a bathroom down here until now; it’s just been roughed in for the last 30 years. The rubber flapper was stuck closed, I had to use a screwdriver to pry it open. Well after doing so everything in the new bathroom works fine now.

My only question is, won’t this rubber piece cause potential clogs?

With toilet paper and other solids that are flushed, is it going to open enough to allow them to flow through?

It opens up quite a bit when the toilet is flushed but I can see how toilet paper and stuff  could be accumulating & eventually clogging it.

[image]